# Java Program using Loops and Jump Statement

Tags: java, loops

I need to create a program that will ask a password three times. But at the third time, having incorrect password, it will just ask for your name. We are asked to use loops on this and jump statements. Please help. ;)

Comment: jump statement??!? break? Do you have any code to show? Will make people here much more inclined to help.;

Comment: And what's problem? Show you code and explain your problem more.

Comment: Have you not read the comments on your other "gimme teh codez" question? What have you tried so far? You have little odds of someone coding a entire solution for you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5201836/write-a-program)

Comment: Don't just repost the same question. We are still not going to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 2):

It's general algoritm,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   if (i == 2 and password != true_password)
      ask_name();
}
```

But for more you can give your code.

p.s. declare i in the loop, thank you @glowcoder for remark.

Comment: Any reason (other than maybe you're a C programmer) that you declare `int i` outside of the loop? You'll find that rather frowned upon in the Java world (Effective Java Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables)

Comment: @glowcoder, thank you for your remark, you right i'm C programmer and java beginner. Thank you